# spring jsp <%%> is visible on page

Tags: java, spring, jsp

Hello I have problem with jsp tags <% %> it is still visible on page and server is not execute code.I made structure of WEB-INF add jsp file change properties

```
spring.mvc.view.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.mvc.view.suffix=.jsp
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=/WEB-INF/jsp/
spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.jsp
```

and add dependency to pom

```
        <dependency>
          <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
          <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>org.apache.tomcat.embed</groupId>
          <artifactId>tomcat-embed-jasper</artifactId>
          <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
        <dependency>
          <groupId>javax.servlet</groupId>
          <artifactId>jstl</artifactId>
          <scope>provided</scope>
        </dependency>
```

its some of my jsp tag i add

```
<!doctype html>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
<html lang="en">
<head>
.
.
.
 <% for (int i =0;i<10;i++)
 out.println(i); %>
```

and that its seen by website

[image: https://imgur.com/g5CQKMp]

Please help thanks

Comment: Why is your Thymeleaf prefix/suffix the same as the JSP prefix/suffix?

Answer (score 0):

How can you use Thymeleaf without adding the Thymeleaf dependency in your pom.xml ??

Add this to your pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.thymeleaf</groupId>
    <artifactId>thymeleaf</artifactId>
    <version>3.0.11.RELEASE</version>
</dependency>
```

About jsp file, make sure your header contains

```
<%@ page language="java" contentType="text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1"
    pageEncoding="ISO-8859-1" isELIgnored="false"%>
<%@ taglib prefix="c" uri="http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core"%>
```

Answer (score 0):

In a typical case you keep your thymeleaf based templates in a different folder and retain .html extension.

Try changing configuration to following and move your thymeleaf templates in templates directory.

```
spring.thymeleaf.prefix=/WEB-INF/templates/
spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.html
```